# using jQuery, is it possible to create a google maps style zoom of a collection of divs?

Tags: jquery, zooming

I'm creating a page which has a series of div tags with background colours (it needs to be div tags as it's coming from a database), to which I want to add a zoom from jQuery. Is this possible? All of the zoom plugins require an image to work, and if I zoom each individual div I lose the center point of where I want to zoom in to.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to calculate how much the divs will grow or shrink after moving the zoom slider and apply the results to the divs like here: [resize div zoom in zoom out using pure javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919521/resize-div-zoom-in-zoom-out-using-pure-javascript-or-jquery)

The size of the div must be calculated for every div-tag you want to zoom.

If the font should be resized you have to compute the font size, too.

Comment: Just what I thought, it will be a case of enlarging the div tags and offsetting them 50%, cheers for the confirmation :)